# namespacing with js prototype framework

Tags: prototypejs

When you create a class in the name space of example.

em.components.grid

```
em.components.grid.Popup = Class.create(
{
  initialize: function(params){
    ...
  },

  show:function(){
    // create or show 
  }
});
```

Does this mean in other classes I have access to the show method if I use the namespace path above.

```
// Another class in prototype
em.components.grid.Popup.show();
```

Or does your new class your trying to access show from have to be in the same namespace.

Is namespacing kind of like packages in other languages. So by giving a namespace you can keep all your classes related to for example grid in one name space and possible other classes unrelated to grid in another namespace.

**Update**
This raises 2 other questions, lets say i create my class like above with the same namespace. Then in another js document I instantiate the class

```
var popup = new em.components.grid.Popup()
```

Then popup would be a global variable not? which I don't want to have in my files if possible. Seen as I have went to all the trouble of giving it a unique name space. To then create an instance of the class on a global variable somewhere else in a js file.

So in the case of a popup is it best to have it global or would it be best to create it on a rollover event and remove it on a rollout event.

```
//pseudo code
  $$('domelementClass').observe('mouseover', function(event) { 
      var popup= new em.components.grid.Popup(event.target);
   })
```

the issue I see with above is I have no reference to remove it on the rollout.

```
  $$('domelementClass').observe('mouseout', function(event) { 
     popup.remove();
   })
```

Comment: Anyone Can explain this to me?

Comment: Anyone please help with this? I updated my question to help explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Namespacing has the same purpose of packaging, avoiding collision. As your example above shows, in JavaScript, you namespace functions and variables by making them properties of an object.

> Does this mean in other classes I have access to the show method if I
>   use the namespace path above.
>
> // Another class in prototype em.components.grid.Popup.show();

In this case no because 'show()' is an instance method, it can only be called once you have a new Popup. You can use your namespaced Popup as an instance in another class or if you want to call show like a static method in Java then you would call Popup.prototype.show();

```
var Popup = Class.create({
    initialize: function(params){
        alert("I exist");
    },

    show:function(){
        alert("show!");
    }
});

// Popup.show(); // would error:

// Uncaught TypeError: Object function klass() {
//     this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
//   } has no method 'show'

Popup.prototype.show();

foo = new Popup();

foo.show();
```

Some useful links:

http://michaux.ca/articles/javascript-namespacing

http://blog.anselmbradford.com/2009/04/09/object-oriented-javascript-tip-creating-static-methods-instance-methods/

Comment: Thanks Kreek. So that would mean then foo is now a global variable. In your example to match my namespace would this work also. em.components.grid.Popup.prototype.show().

Comment: Also another question if I instantiate the class with the new syntax how would I remove the class in the case of a Popup. So if I created the class on rollover would I need to remove it on rolloff. Or would it be better to create the class and then just hide elements on the screen. This way the class just gets created once.

Comment: If you create the instance within a function - var foo = new em.components.grid.Popup() - it would be a local variable and would be destroyed after the function exits.

Comment: $$(element).observe('mouseover', function(event) { new em.components.grid.Popup().show() }).  How would I have a reference to remove it on the rollout without instantiating the class somewhere globally. And then just using a show and hide of the popup instead.

Comment: I would just want to create it using the element as the holder on the rollover and remove it from the element on the rollover. But not sure if its best to create it as a global class on the document and show and hide it based on rollover events. Trying to see whats the better approach. Maybe this is a separate post.

Comment: Ok, let me know if I'm wrong, you want the rollover object to have no reference to the PopUp. In that case have the rollover object fire off an event and have the parent object/document listen for 'show' and 'hide' events and handle the showing/hiding (including creation/destruction of the PopUp). You can use Prototype's fire to send out events http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/fire.

Comment: See my update in the original question. Hopefully that will clear up what I'm trying to do. I guess I'mm looking to see whats the best approach to going about making a tooltip that will load above an element on rollover